# How can I insert union tables to table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, union, sql-insert

I have this query and insert rows to MYSQl database and work perfect.

```
insert int test(id,user)
select null,user from table2
union 
select null,user from table3
```

But when run the above query in PostgreSQL not work. And I get this error `column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type text`, But when I run two query below as shown as worked.

When I run below query in PostgreSQL it works properly:

```
insert into test(id,user)
select null,user from table2
```

Or below query in PostgreSQL it works properly:

```
insert int test(id,user)
select null,user from table3
```

Or below query in PostgreSQL it works properly:

```
select null,user from table2
union 
select null,user from table3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is not a real value and thus has no data type. The default *assumed* data type is `text`, that's where the error message comes from. Just cast the value to `int` in the first SELECT:

```
insert into test(id, "user")
select null::int, "user" from table2
union 
select null, "user" from table3
```

Or even better, leave out the `id` completely so that any default defined for the `id` column is used. It sounds strange to try and insert `null` into a column named `id`

```
insert into test("user")
select "user" from table2
union 
select "user" from table3
```

Note that `user` is a reserved keyword and a built-in function, so you will have to quote it to avoid problems. In the long run I recommend to find a different name for that column.